# What is the problem while i am trying to run Asp Net BoilerPlate Project ABP

Tags: initialization, ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate, abp, aspnetzero

I have found out a video about first configurations and run the ABP project. I have applied instructions of this video step by step but there are some problems on running.

For example video created the DB with migrator project at first step. Ok It works. And the second step he runs the Web project on browser. The login page appears with styles.(My login styles is nowtworking.) He log on with admin user and password(I can not because there are any seed data on DB how can i set initialized data?)

What may be the problem of my project? May i be skipped the required step?

The screenshots about what I told up:
The login screen which is shown on tutorial: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0kAz.png)

The login screen which I have seen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47hE.png)

The returned screen when I tried to login with admin user: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzpbG.png)

The video link:https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJzyIFfAlp8&list=PLsNclT2aHJcPNaCf7Io3DbMN6yAk_DgWJ&index=2

The documentation link which is so confused and hard to learn! :  https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Running-Solution?UI=MVC&DB=EF&Tiered=No

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems like you are getting an undefined user error. First, the project you want to upload is Asp.Net BoilerPlate, the document you published and the youtube images belong to ABP Framework. If you want to create a new project with the ABP framework, follow the steps:

First type abp new `BookStore` to create a new application solution in cli.

Then run the `Db.Migrator` project by opening the installed solution in an IDE (you may want to change the connection string specific to your machine, please [check](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Connection-Strings)).

After the `Db.Migrator` project runs smoothly; your database will be installed.

Then, before running the Web project, open it in the terminal and run `abp install-libs`. This will help you install the npm packages.

Once done, you can run the Web project and log in. Please write here if you have any problems.

If ycreateate a project with Asp.Net BoilerPlate, please review the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents).

Comment: I have read the documentations and videos but documents are different than the project which downloaded from here: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates
I have downloaded MVC project. I have migrated the db successfully. But abp library can not be setup. There are some issues like that: 
PM> abp --version
ABP CLI 7.1.1
PM> abp install-libs
ABP CLI 7.1.1
No project found in the directory.
(By the way im on the true folder which is web project...)


I have tried different ways but I have failed all... I think The new demonstration video is must  for ABP first run...

Comment: Which project do you want to install? ABP Framework and ASP.NET Boilerplate are different platforms. You want to install ABP Framework in your project using ASP.NET Boilerplate; this is not the right behavior. The video you are watching is a training video for ABP Framework.

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, I am not aware that they are different platforms. 
I will try the right instructions about right platform, and i will let you know about result. Thank you for warning me!